# Can I download samples & demos available online for ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, download, sample

Can I download [samples & demos](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/) available online for ExtJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [download ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/products/js/download.php) itself, it contains the samples.

Look in `ext/examples` (and `ext/docs` for the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

view the source of the page and open the linked scripts. Sometimes they are even linked directly.

Answer (score 0):

they are included in the ExtJs Download look under the examples directory